# Not able to send mails in wso2 emm to my id

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I was configuring the mail configs for sending invitation mails for enrolling devices, in wso2 EMM, in the axis2.xml file , if i change the port number which is by default 587 to 25, will it work or i have to use 587 port only.

Comment: Can you post the exception that you get when the port is set to 25 and also the EMM version you are using.

Comment: Are you trying to enroll Android or iOS device? Are you seeing any errors in the logs? Did it work for you with 587 as the SMTP port?

Comment: Also what is the mail.smtp.host you used in your configuration?

Answer (score 1):

The Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP) port 587 is the default port for SMTP Servers to receives mails from external clients.
The SMTP port 25 is for relaying messages from a mail server to another.

Port 25 can sometimes be blocked by residential ISPs and Cloud Hosting Providers.

Changing the port might cause an issue in sending the mail.